# Why is this matrix always symmetric?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, block-matrices

In repeated computations of a large block matrix, I have noticed that a particular block is always symmetric.

It is the following matrix:
$$
B\left[\left(I-\frac{h^2}{8}A^{-1}B\right)^{-1}+\frac12 I\right],
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric and positive-definite, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $h\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.

At first, I thought that this was trivial because $A$ and $B$ are both symmetric, and the other matrix involved is the identity.

However, taking a closer look, I fail to see why would this matrix reveal to be symmetric because the product $A^{-1}B$ is not symmetric. Therefore, neither the sum $I-\frac{h^2}{8}A^{-1}B$, nor its inverse, are symmetric. Then the product

$$
B\left(I-\frac{h^2}{8}A^{-1}B\right)^{-1}
$$

has no reason to by symmetric. Or is it?

Is there a particular property that I am forgetting here? How can I prove that this block is always symmetric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An  initial simplification helps.
Absorb $\frac{h^2}{8}$ into $B$ and forget about it.

Now note that since $B$ is symmetric, our given matrix is symmetric if and only if $X:=B(I-A^{-1}B)^{-1}$ is symmetric.

But $X$ is symmetric if and only if $X^{-1}$ is symmetric. As $(I-A^{-1}B)B^{-1}=B^{-1}(I-BA^{-1})$ we are done.

Comment: For the final step, I think it is even easier to see that $X^{-1}$ has the form $(I-A^{-1}B)B^{-1} = B^{-1}-A^{-1}$, a difference of symmetric matrices, which is of course symmetric.

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim That's very neat. I just hacked it out.

Comment: Very neat. Specially including the observation above.